# android: How to increase long press time for listview items in android?

Tags: android, long-press

I have a *custom* `listview`, in which items are scroll *horizontal*. I want to perform single touch and longpress for items for 5 sec for `listview` items. How to do this. How can i increase `longpress` time interval for `listview` items to 5 sec.

Answer (score 2):

This replicates onLongPress more accurately because it does not wait for the user to lift their finger before executing. Was written specifically for ViewPager, but should be able to apply similar logic.

```
// long press duration in milliseconds
public static final int LONG_PRESS_DURATION = 2000;

private boolean mIsTouching = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mIsTouching = true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP) {
        mIsTouching = false;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

    // subtracts the system set timeout since that time has already occured at this point
    int duration = LONG_PRESS_DURATION - getLongPressTimeout();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mIsTouching) {
                do something...
            }
        }
    }, duration > 0 ? duration : 0);
}
```

Comment: Where's the `onLongPress(MotionEvent)` method? I can't find it in `ViewPager`. Do you mean the `onLongClick(View view)` in `View.OnLongClickListener`?

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me, although I had to remove the getLongPressTimeout() from your solution.

Comment: This can be done more simply by starting the postDelayed in `onTouchEvent`/ACTION_DOWN. There, it is not necessary to subtract getLongPressTimeout.  Do not need `onLongPress`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation: **(You don't need to release to shot the action)**

```
Handler longTouchHandler= new Handler();
static final int longduration=10000;//10000ms press duration
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN) {
        longTouchHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.w("Longpress","longpressed");
            }
        }, longduration);
        return true;
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP) {
        longTouchHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        Log.w("Longpress","cancelled");
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `setOnItemLongClickListener`, then you can set the view you touch a `OnTouchListener`, you can record the time when `ACTION_DOWN` and the time `ACTION_UP`, so you can calculate if the time is more than 5 sec between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

Comment: IMO that would be an unnatural usecase because we usually wait for the popup or any changes before we release the finger, the user does not typically count `1.2.3.4.5` then release.

Comment: To clarify Enzokie's comment: if you wait for ACTION_UP to calculate the time, user has no way of knowing when they have held it long enough. Instead, the action should be triggered on a delay after ACTION_DOWN, if the finger is still touching. See Denver's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the delay. It is hardwired in the android framework. I also came across same problem days ago.

You can use `setOnTouchListener` for it manually.

Example :

```
private long then;
private int longClickDur= 5000; //5 seconds


//you can use any view you want
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.longclick_view);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          then = (long) System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > longClickDuration) {
            /* Long click behaviour will go here*/
            Toast.makeText(context, "yay, long click", Toast.LENGTH.SHORT);
            return false;
          } else {
            /* LONG CLICK FAILED*/
            Toast.makeText(context, "TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH.SHORT);
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: I did the same thing, but in that case, horizontal scrolling of listview not happening....

Comment: This has the same problem that Enzokie mentioned on juemuren's answer:  this does not give USER any feedback as to when they have held the touch long enough. See Denver's answer for better approach.

Comment: this is long click, not long press