# Long Press duration on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way in Xamarin Forms to customize the long press duration for Android and iOS? I believe the default duration is 1 second for each platform, but some of my users have been complaining that the long press events have been firing too quickly as they scroll through lists, etc. in my app. So I'd love to be able to bump that out to say 2 seconds on each platform. Any ideas?

Ideally I'd like to solve this issue by increasing the duration before a long press event is fired. If this isn't possible, is it possible to implement my own long press using a timer? I've seen a great example with a button using behaviors and the button's Pressed/Released events, but ideally I'd like this code to work for any control not just buttons and other controls don't have a Pressed/Released event.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi check this https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I already have code that will do a long press similar to your example. What I'm looking to do is be able to customize the length of time the user presses down before the long press event gets fired.

Comment: NOTE: [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120416/199364) now includes a standard behavior for Long Press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **iOS**, you can change the `MinimumPressDuration` of UILongPressGestureRecognizer to achieve that.

> It's the minimum time, in seconds, fingers must press for the gesture
>   to be recognized. Default is 0.5.

Code is :

```
public iOSLongPressedEffect()
{
    _longPressRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick);
    _longPressRecognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 5;
}
```

In **Android**, it seems you can't change the duration directly. You have to implement your own logic in the method `OnTouchListener` to achieve that.

Have a look at these threads may help:

[change-long-click-delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958418/change-long-click-delay)

[android-how-to-increase-long-press-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327179/android-how-to-increase-long-press-time-for-listview-items-in-android)

[how-can-i-increase-the-clicktime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934245/longclick-event-happens-too-quickly-how-can-i-increase-the-clicktime-required-t)

BTW, in [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3480) in Github of Xamarin.forms,  there says a `LongPressGestureRecognizer` api would be added in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the information! That helped me get past the issue I was hitting.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached a Behavior to a button to get both long press and tap gestures

```cs
public class LongPressBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    private Timer _timer;
    private volatile bool _isReleased;
    private object _context;

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(LongPressBehavior), default(ICommand));
    public static readonly BindableProperty EarlyReleaseCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EarlyReleaseCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(LongPressBehavior), default(ICommand));
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(LongPressBehavior));
    public static readonly BindableProperty DurationProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Duration), typeof(int), typeof(LongPressBehavior), 1000);

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand EarlyReleaseCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(EarlyReleaseCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(EarlyReleaseCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public int Duration
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(DurationProperty);
        set => SetValue(DurationProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(ImageButton bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.Pressed += Button_Pressed;
        bindable.Released += Button_Released;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ImageButton bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.Pressed -= Button_Pressed;
        bindable.Released -= Button_Released;
    }

    private void DeInitializeTimer()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            if (_timer == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(Timer_Elapsed, null, Duration, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _isReleased = false;
        _context = (sender as ImageButton)?.BindingContext;
        InitializeTimer();
    }

    private void Button_Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isReleased)
        {
            EarlyReleaseCommand?.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
        _isReleased = true;
        _context = null;
        DeInitializeTimer();
    }

    protected virtual void OnLongPressed()
    {
        if (Command != null && Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
        {
            if (CommandParameter == null && Command.CanExecute(_context))
            {
                Command.Execute(_context);
                return;
            }
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }

    public LongPressBehavior()
    {
        _isReleased = true;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object state)
    {
        DeInitializeTimer();
        if (_isReleased)
        {
            return;
        }
        _isReleased = true;
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(OnLongPressed);
    }
}
```

You can use it as:

```xml
<Button Text="Long Press Me!">
    <Button.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:LongPressBehavior Command="{Binding LongPressCommand}" EarlyReleaseCommand="{Binding TapCommand}" Duration="5000" />
    </Button.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Comment: NOTE: [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66120416/199364) now includes a standard behavior for Long Press.